# How executable jar copy its relative resources folder contents to local filesystem and vice versa

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant, executable-jar

I created an `executable jar` of `javaFX application` using `Eclipse`. 
  Project hiearchy before created `executable jar`.

```
       --------Project_Name

               ------------src

                           ---------(default package)
                                    -----------------Main.java

                           ---------data(folder)

                           ---------Resources(folder)
                                    ---------mongod.exe
```

**Application FLow :**

- When user double click on `executable jar` application first create folder having name `mongodb` in user space  (local filesystem or system folder or external to jar) in `C` drive for `Windows` , then copy `Resources` folder content to this `monogdb` directory e:g `C:\mongodb`.
- Second check its `data` folder inside `jar` . If its empty create `db`folder in `C` drive in user space (local file system or external to jar) e:g `C:\db` . and If its not empty create `db` folder in user space (local file system or external to jar) e:g `C:\db` and copy `data` folder (inside jar folder)  contents to `db`(user space or local folder). and delete `data` folder (inside jar folder) contents.
- Application is saving text files in `mongodb` database and have `menu bar` option name `Send to USB` on click on Send to Usb will send local file system folder `db` (which is `C`drive e:g`C:\db`) contents (contents will be files)  to `data` folder which is  inside `jar`.

**Question**

1. Is it possible to copy folder contents which is inside `jar` to local folder or vice versa , if yes then how ??
2. Is it possible to delete folder content inside `jar` ??
3. Is there any method like `getResourceStream` ( used to get relative resource files) which can get the realtive path of folder for the copy purpose???
4. Or should I use `Ant Task`or `Maven`for this , if yes then kindly provide specific content ????
5. Any Other strategy to accomplish this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At runtime, there is no efficient way to treat the inside of your jar file in the classpath as a file system and copy things out. The classpath API doesn't treat packages as directories. There are, then, two directions you can go instead.

1. Put these resources into a tar or jar inside your jar, and then use the usual open source libraries (commons-compress, etc) to read them from the classpath and write them to the file system.
2. If you are sure that your jar file will be used in a plain old boring URLClassLoader, you can parse the java.class.path system property, find your jar's pathname in there, open your own input stream to it, and then use the standard Java classes for reading a Jar file to read things out of it (and then you can write them where you like).